# Prometheus Exporter is unreachable, what is way to investigate?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I would assume it's more or less common case. 
Sometimes we can observe gaps in time series data in Prometheus.

After investigation, we found:

1. Prometheus was up all time and information from other exporters were exist.
2. According to "up" metric , exporter was unreachable.
3. Exporter pod was alive
4. Looks like exporter application by itself was alive as well, due to some messages in syslog.

Hence, i can conclude we have network problem, which i have no idea how to debug in k8, either Prometheus ignores one exporter (usually the same one) time to time.

Thanks for any hints

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/29/kube-proxy-subtleties-debugging-an-intermittent-connection-reset/

Comment: Thanks @TummalaDhanvi , it can be the case due to we use 1.14XXXX , i will check.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to confirm the availability of the exporter is using periodic scraping manually (using a script with curl for example). Or using a scraping tool such as Metricat (https://metricat.dev/).

If you set up interval small enough you might see small windows of unavailability.